# How to install a "pdf printer"?

Tags: printing, pdf

Is there a way to install a printer that prints to pdf?

There's a lot of discussions about this in the web foruns, but none seens to work.

Comment: A more up to date answer can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601836/cups-pdf-prints-a-blank-page/639883#639883)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ubuntu ships with this functionality. Try opening gedit or another GUI text editor and clicking the print button:

[image]

When the Print dialog appears, select the "Print to File" printer and select a location for the PDF. After clicking Print, you should end up with a PDF file in that location containing an identical copy of what would have printed on a sheet of paper.

[image]

Comment: It's correct, the problem is with wine! Apps running under wine will not have access to this printer.. :(

Comment: The [`cups-pdf` printer](http://askubuntu.com/q/81851/20661) is available also for applications running under `wine`.

Comment: a lot of other image and text viewers and editors have this option

Comment: This built in printer only shows up in certain applications... For example, it doesn't show up in Thunderbird or LibreOffice.

Comment: Using this you have to be careful of not overwriting your last printed file.

Answer (score 118):

If you've [CUPS](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/cups.html) installed, you can easily add a "PDF Printer" by installing the [cups-pdf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cups-pdf) package:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

or since Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-cups-pdf
```

The pdf printer provided by that package will "print" the resulting PDFs into the `/home/[user]/PDF` directory.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 16.04, the package is called `printer-driver-cups-pdf`.

Comment: I get blank output files

Comment: It can take a minute or so to complete "printing."  So if you're getting blank pages or a "corrupted pdf," just give it a few minutes and check back later.

Comment: since Ubuntu 18.04 the cups-pdf and its successor printer-driver-cups-pdf do not work any more. The "printer" disappears. Any idea how to print PDF from wine based apps??

Comment: Note that when using `sudo apt install cups-pdf` at least, the new "printer" that shows up in your print menu is called simply `PDF`, and when you select this printer and click the "Print" button, it then outputs the generated PDFs into this folder: `~/PDF`, with a file name such as `job_217-untitled_document.pdf`. It took me a while to find them, as it looked like nothing was happening, and no dialog box came up (in typical Linux fashion: not very user-friendly!)

Comment: @opinion_no9: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090245/cups-pdf-disappeared-with-update-to-u-18-04 for 18.04 fix.

Comment: Ran `sudo apt install cups-pdf` in Ubuntu 21.04.  
`apt` automatically detects this:  
`Note, selecting 'printer-driver-cups-pdf' instead of 'cups-pdf'`  
and installs `printer-driver-cups-pdf` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you print , there is already an option for "print to file".
I hope you are talking about that.. if not then please elaborate your question

Comment: Yes, depending on the software you are using there's already this option. But for Astah UML, for example, there isn't. I would like something like the "print2pdf" software (this one, for Windows).

Comment: Yes, this is independent from "print to file".      

apt-get install cups-pdf is back for a while.        In Ubuntu 19 and 20 I could use it again. Works fine. mostly. Acts like a printer (same like the Redmond workaround).