# CUPS-PDF prints a blank page

Tags: printing, pdf

I am a new Ubuntu user. I installed `cups-pdf` to print a PDF file, but every time I try to print, I get one blank page, no matter how many pages I try to print.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.cups-pdf.de/documentation.shtml

Comment: This question is ambiguous, please specify whether you want to print a pdf file on paper, or any file using a mock printer to produce a pdf file. Since you're using `cups-pdf`, I presume it's the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Its a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/+bug/1236120) in `cups-pdf`.
After installation, cups's pdf-printer doesn't get configured properly. To get it working you do the following:

1. Open a web-browser, and go to `http://localhost:631`.
2. Go to **Administration > Manage Printers > (your pdf printer) > Modify Printer**.
3. Provide your login credentials.
4. Click **Continue** for the connection and name page.
5. On the third page, when you are asked to enter the model of the printer, click **Choose File**, to select the PPD file.
6. Navigate and select `/usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF.ppd`.
7. Click **Modify Printer**.
8. Go to Terminal and restart cups using the command:

   ```
   sudo service cups restart
   ```

   and voila! you are done.

PDFs will get printed in your `/home/username/PDF` directory.

Comment: First install: `$ sudo apt install printer-driver-cups-pdf` (or if you're running < 16.04, `$ sudo apt-get install cups-pdf`). With 16.04, at least, I didn't have to restart cups, but YMMV. I installed the `printer-driver-cups-pdf` package on a brand new copy of 18.04 and it configured the PDF printer for me _sans_ bug! (they fixed it)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have Kubuntu 18.04 and for one thing, there's no such file as `/usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF.ppd` on my drive. Instead, I have `/usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF_noopt.ppd` and `/usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd` and none of them work.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.

Just get the PostScript Driver and it works fine!

Or install this `"PRINTER MODEL" CUPS + GutenPrint`

I don't know why PLC 6/ PXL doesn't work, but if you install PostScript it  will work!

Comment: I am not able to get to know what is the package name to install and how. Is there any package with all capital name? Please don't post anything with such format. Please come with a clean, step by step solution with all needed detail to know what the problem is and how your solution is going to solve the problem.