# Printing PDF - Blank Page

Tags: printing

I have newly installed Ubuntu 18.04. When printing a pdf it just prints a single blank page. I have tried other pdf software (Okular and Adobe Reader) and tried to reinstall CUPS but nothing works. The printer works on LibreOffice. The printer is a Laser Brother HL-L2340D.I have also run a software update. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CUPS-PDF prints a blank page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601836/cups-pdf-prints-a-blank-page)

Comment: This is NOT about the CUPS-PDF driver that produces a PDF file, but about printing a PDF to paper, so *NOT* a duplicate.

Comment: Does printing from e.g. gedit (the Text Editor) works?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for thinking of me