# cups-pdf disappeared with update to U 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, pdf, virtual-printer

The virtual PDF printer is no longer available. It was based on cups-pdf. Since 18.04 it is gone. 
No error message. Just disappeared in GUI for printer control. 
Worked fine before the upgrade.

New install of cups-pdf is possible but does not help. It tells:

```
    [...]
        Note, selecting 'printer-driver-cups-pdf' instead of 'cups-pdf'
        printer-driver-cups-pdf is already the newest version (3.0.1-5). 
[...]
```

But not a trace of PDF printer functionality in the gui printer setup.
Applications do no longer show the cups-pdf "printer".

Question:
How can I get the (cups-) pdf back in 18.04? 
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Bug opened: 1801805 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/+bug/1801805

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not occuring if the distro-update to Ubuntu 18.n did never have an installation of cups-pdf before. So it is clearly update related.

This process provides a **workaround** (does not always help):

1. Purge cups-pdf

   ```
   sudo apt -y purge cups-pdf
   ```
2. Purge the substitute-stuff (since 16.n)

   ```
   sudo apt -y purge printer-driver-cups-pdf
   ```
3. Clean up.

   ```
   sudo  apt-get install  check
   sudo apt -y autoremove
   ```
4. Reboot. (smart guys will find a way to just restart the services ;-) )

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. Reinstall cups-pdf.

   ```
   sudo apt -y install -V cups-pdf
   ```

   Monitor closely if it provides positive comments.

   Out of curiosity: Please watch out if there is a PPD update process mentioned in the last installation step (up to now only traced in totally new installs).
6. Check.

   The result in the GUI menu: In "Printers" PDF should be back.

   If PDF doesn't come back in the Printers menu leave a comment here and submit a bug report mentioning bug 1801805 (link in comment above). *This workaround is not the solution for the root cause!* It may be important for the developer to get more details from different machines.

Comment: meanwhile I read the responsible entity for this problem is "app armor".  

There is a long and interesting discussion of several(!) ways to fix the app armor failures here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cupsys/+bug/147551


A few key words here (all references in the bug mentioned above!):
sudo vim /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf
sudo vim   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd   (this is the nuisance) 
other issues: 
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
sudo aa-complain cupsd  (kind of disables strict apparmor for cups)

Comment: This worked for me without having to reboot at step 4.

Comment: I did `sudo systemctl restart cups-browsed cups` for step 4

Answer (score 1):

As of Ubuntu 18.04, the package name is `printer-driver-cups-pdf`, and the default directory of printing is `/home/user/PDF/`.

At your situation I would try to purge and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I had been avoiding cups-pdf believing that I was responsible for it not behaving on my machine.

When I realised the same thing was happening under Mint 19.1 as well as Ubuntu 18.04 (and found the time), I found your work-around above.

However, when I redirected the 'Out' statement in cups-pdf.conf to:

Out /home//Documents/pdf_files

instead of:

Out {HOME}/PDF

it failed.

When I changed it back, it worked again.

Comment: Clearly noted in the `cups-pdf.conf` that AppArmor settings has to be updated. More info at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cupsys/+bug/147551

Comment: You need to edit the apparmour setting file

sudo gedit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd
#at the bottom after the default home PDF add your path
  @{HOME}/Documents/pdf_files/ rw,
  @{HOME}/Documents/pdf_files/* rw,

restart apparmour
sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service