# How do I install a pdf printer for Foxit pdf reader on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: printing, pdf, foxitreader

I have some pdfs that I have commented out that I'd like to reprint as pdf to make the comments permanent. Foxit does not come with the 'Save to file' option like pre-installed Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) apps

Comment: You can use Xournal++to edit pdfs and export them

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I did some digging and found this [old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81817/how-to-install-a-pdf-printer?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C83.3963) on using CUPS. It then occurred to me that I can add new printers under Settings. Here's what I did:

1. Settings > Printers > Click 'Additional Printer Settings...'
2. Click the big [(+) Add] button
3. Under Select Device, click on `Generic CUPS-BRF`. Click 'Forward'

[print-menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjUrM.png)

4. Once its done searching for drivers, select 'Generic' and click 'Forward' again
5. Under 'Models', click on 'PDF' then 'Forward' again
6. Now name your new pdf printer and click 'Apply'. You'll be prompted to print a test page. Clicking 'Print Test Page' will have a .brf file appear in `home/BRF`. It's ok to rename it as .pdf.

Restart Foxit. Opening the Print options will now show the new pdf printer. I named mine `Generic-CUPS-BRF-pdf-Printer`

[new-pdf-printer-in-foxit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzaip.png)