How do I integrate print to pdf to work with a program running in wine?
I have a program running in wine, but I want to print the project output.
when I try printing, it says resource not found.
I tried adding a link to cups-pdf, that wasn't recognized.
I tried adding ghostscript, and cutePDF, still, not recognized.
I really thought linking the cups-pdf service would have worked, but I appear to be missing something. I asked ChatGPT, but it seems to be hallucinating some interfaces not present in WINE.
Is there a way to make a default pdf printer in wine?
Ubuntu Mate, 22.04
lpstat -a | grep -i pdf PDF accepting requests since Sat 20 Jul 2024 05:43:55 PM EDT 
Printing pdf in MsOS works just fine.
Project files, are mixed data, XML, binary.
(Looked into that further, looks like its DEC TOPS-20 from a PDP-10, compressed with gzip, which is weird, but not really sure how that helps, Im not trying to print the binary.)

What version of Ubuntu are you using? What are the exact commands you are using? Please update the question and add this info, not in comments.

What is the extension of the output file?

This question is similar to: Using Wine for Windows printer driver on Linux. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is the output of lpstat -a | grep -i pdf? Wine will use any printers that your Ubuntu system has. Please, install the PDF printer driver as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/81851/855322 if it is missing.
